# insert into DB table java

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, insert

I want to fill a table using insert statement. To get the data I used arrays that contain the data I need.

I want to insert the id and some other values in this format.

```
id w0   w1   w2    w3
1  0.0  1.0  0.54 0.0 
2  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.8 
and others
```

id ---> read from a normal array

the other numbers ---> read from a 2d array

and I want for each new row a new id.

The problem I have is the rows are moving and incrementing while the id is stuck in 0, so each new row is added with the same id which is wrong since the id is a primary key.

```
String sqlselect=new String("select k_id from keywordsTable");
        ResultSet rss = stmt1.executeQuery(sqlselect);
        kId=new String[numOfFields];
        String f="";
        String ff="";
        String ffff="";
            for (int i=0;i<kId.length;i++) {
                while(rss.next())   
                {
                kId[i]=rss.getString(1);
                f="w"+kId[i]+ " varchar(20)";
                ff+="w"+kId[i]+", ";
                ffff+="w"+kId[i]+", ";
                //fff+="w"+kId[i]+ " varchar(20), ";
                String sqlalter=new String("ALTER TABLE "+ tableName +" add "+f+"");
                //System.out.println(sqlalter);
                stmt1.executeUpdate(sqlalter);
            }

        }
            ff = ff.replaceAll(", $","");
            ffff = ffff.replaceAll(", $","");


String sqlselectF=new String("select f_id from filesTable");
            ResultSet rssF = stmt1.executeQuery(sqlselectF);
            FId=new String[numOfFiles];

            String matInsert = null;
            String g="";
            String seperator = "";

                for (int s=0;s<FId.length;s++) {
                    while(rssF.next())  
                    {
                    FId[s]=rssF.getString(1);
                    g=seperator+FId[s];

            for (int k=0;k<di.mat.length;k++) {  //row
                String m="";
                String sep = "";
            for (int j=0;j<di.mat[k].length;j++) { //col

                m+= (sep+di.mat[k][j]);
                sep = " ,";
                matInsert=new String("INSERT INTO "+ tableName  +"(id,"+ffff+")"+"values" +"("+g+","+m+")");

        } //col 
            System.out.println("ff="+g);
            System.out.println(matInsert);
            stmt1.executeUpdate(matInsert);

                    } //row


                    } //while

        } //for 1


    seperator=" ,";
```

Comment: You aren't incrementing or setting `g` in your third for loop.

Comment: Not relevant to the question but still important: the names you chose for the variables are horrible (FId, rssF, di, mat, g, sep, m, ffff...), you should consider putting additional thought in choosing more meaningful names.

Comment: @alfasin thank you very much for the advice. I know I am not using good names they are temporary I will change them when I will finish coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't insert IDs, configure the column as **[AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)** and let MySQL assign the IDs upon each INSERT.

Second, the nesting of `while` loop inside a `for` loop is probably a logical mistake.
Third, `ffff` is not declared anywhere in the code that you posted.
Forth, the INSERT query is missing whitespaces in a few places, it will come out (if all the input is correct) as something like:

```
INSERT INTO tableName(id,ffff)values(x,y)
```

Comment: I want to insert the ids manually, these ids are taken from another table. about the insert statement it is working and I tried it in other cases. I will edit the code to add ffff declaration. Thank you for your time